# How to make android app work in offline mode

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I want to know how I can make my app work in offline when user lost the network connectivity.

I need to post data to the server using **JSON post** method when the user is not connected with wifi or mobile data.

I am using following code to detect the network state using broadcast receiver and don't know how to proceed after this. 
 Please assist me to proceed further.

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null
                && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected) {
            Log.e("NET", "connected" + isConnected);

        } else {
            Log.e("NET", "not connected to internet" + isConnected);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont u save the data in the sqlite database and then when WiFi or mobile data turns on, you can post it to the server

Comment: @Diffy Thanks for your reply. Is it so?? any sample codes to perform the task?? I know to make sqlite setup. But dont know how to process it to broadcast receiver

Comment: are u able to check when your net turns on using broadcast?

Comment: yes i can check the connectivity. that's works fine

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662505/get-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android) post, its given how to fetch data from sqlite database. And then you can post the data to server using [this](http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/) method. You can write all this code in your

```
if(isConnected){


}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to do this for particular activity

Comment: which code do u want me to elaborate? Fetching data or posting data?

Comment: Fetching and posting datas are familiar for me. i need to ellaborate the statement if(isConnected){}

Comment: That is what u have written in your question. If(isConnected),means it willl detect whether net is connected or not and u said its workign fine

Comment: actually i need to send the data in FIFO manner. for example: if i am entering 10 datas means 1st data which was entered by me should post

Comment: so whats the problem here?

Comment: will let you know after completing this.